# Explicit conversion of std::basic_ios to bool

Tags: c++11

I read that since C++11, the conversion from `std::basic_ios` to `bool` is required to be explicit. clang allows to assign the result of `getline` to a bool only after typecasting. What I do not understand is why it accepts the following code:

```
while( getline(inputfile, newline) )
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one exception, however. If, for some expression `e`, the declaration `bool t(e)` is well-formed and in one of the following contexts, the implicit conversion is invoked.

- controlling expression of if, while, for
- the logical operators !, && and ||
- the conditional operator ?:
- static_assert
- noexcept

In the case of `std::basic_ios`, it has an explicit [`bool` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) and thus is eligible for the conversion within the `while` statement.

Take a look at [`Implicit conversions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) for more details.